# Is there any support for arangodb kafka connect source connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, arangodb

Is there any support for arangodb kafka connect source connector ?

Answer (score 0):

I can only find a [sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-arangodb/).